# HttpPost not accepting lengthy url in Java

Tags: java, android, json, http, http-post

Here is my httppost method from my android app. It is not accepting lenthy urls. There is no reponse/exception for lengthy urls. When I enter the same url manually in browser it works fine. Can anyone point out the issue here?

```
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Update:
Added one sample url. The same url works fine when manually entered in browser and it gives response.

```
 url.com/data?format=json&pro={%22merchanturl%22:%22http://url.com/logo.pn‌​g%22,%22price%22:599,%22productDesc%22:%22Apple%2032GBBlack%22,%22prodID%22:%2291‌​3393%22,%22merchant%22:%224536%22,%22prourl%22:%22http://url.com/data%22,%22name%‌​22:%22Apple%2032GB%20%2D%20Black%22,%22productUrl%22:%22http://www.url.com/image.‌​jpg%22,%22myprice%22:550,%22mercname%22:%22hello%22,%22mybool%22:false}
```

Comment: where is the url that you are using ?

Comment: I can't reveal the url. Its official one. Its an API. The same url works fine when I enter it manually in browser.

Comment: Then how can i verify your code?

Comment: @imran I have added the sample url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
}
```

Comment: actually I have a lengthy jsonobject in my url like this {"merchantPrice":"7.69","merchantName":"amazon.com"}. Actual url has has so many json parameters like this. Will this work?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your URL contains things like `index.php?call=getUsers&something=bla`

To solve this you can make use of `NameValuePair` :

```
String url = "http://example.com/index.php";

ArrayList<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("call", "getUsers"));
nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("something", "bla"));

try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    [...]
} catch (Exception e) {
    [...]
}
```

Comment: actually I have a lengthy jsonobject in my url like this {"merchantPrice":"7.69","merchantName":"amazon.com"}. Actual url has has so many json parameters like this. Will this work?

Comment: you can try with my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with the following code. you sould have [Json API](http://www.json.org/).

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonReader {

  private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
  sb.append((char) cp);
}
return sb.toString();
  }

  public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
  String jsonText = readAll(rd);
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
  return json;
} finally {
  is.close();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552");
    System.out.println(json.toString());
    System.out.println(json.get("id"));
  }
```

Comment: my json parser works fine. My doubt is I have lengthy request. That is where the issue is. The response is very small. That is not an issue.

Comment: I hope the lengthy URL shouldn't be an issue. if you have any issues with the request URL, just share us. will try to help you.

Comment: here it is. It works fine when I manually enter in url. http://url.com/data?format=json&pro={%22merchanturl%22:%22http://url.com/logo.png%22,%22price%22:599,%22productDesc%22:%22Apple%2032GBBlack%22,%22prodID%22:%22913393%22,%22merchant%22:%224536%22,%22prourl%22:%22http://url.com/data%22,%22name%22:%22Apple%2032GB%20%2D%20Black%22,%22productUrl%22:%22http://www.url.com/image.jpg%22,%22myprice%22:550,%22mercname%22:%22hello%22,%22mybool%22:false}